# Drupal7 print embed block of view in another views tpl

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I need to print block of view in another view tpl.

I use this: `<?php  print views_embed_view( 'blog_popular','block'); ?>`

`'blog_popular'` is view Machine Name.

But not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
$blockObject = block_load('views', 'blog_popular');
$block = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($blockObject)));
$output = drupal_render($block);
print($output);
```

Comment: I have used block machine name instead of  view machine name

Comment: That's awesome! :p